# Xquery - Selecting value from XML using XMLtable

Tags: xml, db2, xquery

I want to use XQuery to display the value if `FrequencyCdvalue="01"` and `city type="first"` in the following XML.

Can you pls help me here

```
<Envelope>
<Arrangement>
<FrequencyCd value="01">first first</FrequencyCd> 
<FrequencyCd value="02">first second</FrequencyCd> 
<contactinfo> <Address>
<street>234 Rolling Lane</street> 
<city type="first">Rockport</city> 
</Address>
<email>love2fish@finmail.com</email> 
</contactinfo>
</Arrangement>
<Arrangement>
<FrequencyCd value="03">second first</FrequencyCd> 
<FrequencyCd value="04">second second</FrequencyCd> 
<contactinfo>
<Address>
<street>234 Straight Lane</street> 
<city type="first">Crackport</city> 
</Address>
<email>hate2fish@finmail.com</email> 
</contactinfo>
</Arrangement>
</Envelope>
```

Comment: What value are you trying to display? The xpath `/Envelope/Arrangement[FrequencyCd/@value='01' and contactinfo/Address/city/@type='first']` should get you started.

Comment: Thanks a lot Dev - I am able to get the XPATH for this but when I am trying to put this in a Xquery (Actually we need a DB2 query) and display the values for Frequency code 01 and city type = first

Answer (score 2):

This approach shreds more rows internally, but allows the compound filtering criteria (the conditions for FrequencyCd and City) to be implemented as a simple WHERE clause on the SQL representation of the shredded XML data (the output of the XMLTABLE function).

```
with origxml(xdoc) AS (VALUES XMLPARSE( DOCUMENT 
    '<Envelope>
    <Arrangement>
    <FrequencyCd value="01">first first</FrequencyCd> 
    <FrequencyCd value="02">first second</FrequencyCd> 
    <contactinfo> <Address>
    <street>234 Rolling Lane</street> 
    <city type="first">Rockport</city> 
    </Address>
    <email>love2fish@finmail.com</email> 
    </contactinfo>
    </Arrangement>
    <Arrangement>
    <FrequencyCd value="03">second first</FrequencyCd> 
    <FrequencyCd value="04">second second</FrequencyCd> 
    <contactinfo>
    <Address>
    <street>234 Straight Lane</street> 
    <city type="first">Crackport</city> 
    </Address>
    <email>hate2fish@finmail.com</email> 
    </contactinfo>
    </Arrangement>
    </Envelope>'
    )
)
SELECT filteredxml.FrequencyCd, filteredxml.City FROM origxml,
XMLTABLE ('$d/Envelope/Arrangement' PASSING origxml.xdoc AS "d"
                COLUMNS
                FrequencyCd     VARCHAR(20) PATH    'FrequencyCd[@value="01"]/text()',
                City            VARCHAR(30) PATH    'contactinfo/Address/city[@type="first"]/text()'
            ) as filteredxml
WHERE filteredxml.FrequencyCd IS NOT NULL
AND filteredxml.City IS NOT NULL
;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Fred - This worked - Also I have one more requirement where in I should use // (i.e whereever it exists in the XML) i.e use // Arrangement/FrequencyCd[@value="01"] but when I try that I am getting an error.

Comment: Thanks a lot Fred - This worked - Also I have one more requirement where in I should use // (i.e whereever it exists in the XML) i.e use // Arrangement/FrequencyCd[@value="01"] but when I try that I am getting an error. - I also tried removing '$d/Envelope/Arrangement' - Apprecite your help
SELECT filteredxml.FrequencyCd, filteredxml.City FROM testxml,XMLTABLE     ('$d/Envelope/Arrangement' PASSING testxml.contact AS "d" 
COLUMNS FrequencyCd VARCHAR(20) PATH '//FrequencyCd[@value="02"]/text()',City VARCHAR(30) PATH '//contactinfo/Address/city[@type="first"]/text()') as filteredxml

Comment: This is a sample XML and my actual requirement is to work on a bigger xml - I want to know is there a way I can refer to different paths in the same Xquery like  //ABC/DEF/GHI and ??MNO/PQR/STU

Comment: XMLTABLE needs to know what your row-producing expression is in order to work. If your XML document is not organized in a way that makes sense as a table, you won't be able to get the results you want in a single XMLTABLE call. In those situations, you could join more than one XMLTABLE expression together, or run the document through XSLTRANSFORM to radically reorganize it in order to make it work with one XMLTABLE expression.